# python scrapy only pulling first row but repeating for the correct amount of items in the table

Tags: python, scrapy

like the title says. my scrapy code seems to be running correctly except it is pulling only the first row of table and repeating it for the amount of rows in the table.

```html
import scrapy


class FightersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fighters"

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all'
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        for fighter in response.xpath('//*[@class="b-statistics__table"]//tbody/tr'):
            yield {
                'first': fighter.xpath('//td[1]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'last': fighter.xpath('//td[2]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'nickname': fighter.xpath('//td[3]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'height': fighter.xpath('//td[4]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'weight': fighter.xpath('//td[5]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'reach': fighter.xpath('//td[6]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'stance': fighter.xpath('//td[7]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'wins': fighter.xpath('//td[8]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'losses': fighter.xpath('//td[9]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'draws': fighter.xpath('//td[10]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
            }
```

if i take out the `_first` it pulls all of the data but puts it in the same cell and repeats the same way.

```html
first   last    nickname    height  weight  reach   stance  wins    losses
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
Tom Aaron   The Assassin    --  155 lbs.    --      5   3
....
```

Comment: you have to use relative `xpath` - it has to start with dot `fighter.xpath('.// ...')`. Without dot it is absolute `xpath` and it always start searching from the beginning of HTML  and it always find the same element(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `relative xpath` to search only inside `fighter` - it has to start with `dot`

```
fighter.xpath('.//td[1]/a//text()')
```

Without `dot` it is `absolute xpath` and it searchs in all HTML and it always finds first row.

---

But then you will have other problem.

You get all rows in table - even header which doesn't have `td` - and you have to skip it. You can slice it with `[1:]`

```
for fighter in response.xpath(...)[1:]:
```

---

Minimal working code.

You can copy all to file and start it as normal script `python script.py` without creating project in `scrapy`

```
import scrapy


class FightersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fighters"

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all'
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        for fighter in response.xpath('//*[@class="b-statistics__table"]//tbody/tr')[1:]:
            print(fighter.xpath('.//td[4]'))
            yield {
                'first': fighter.xpath('.//td[1]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'last': fighter.xpath('.//td[2]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'nickname': fighter.xpath('.//td[3]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'height': fighter.xpath('.//td[4]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'weight': fighter.xpath('.//td[5]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'reach': fighter.xpath('.//td[6]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'stance': fighter.xpath('.//td[7]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'wins': fighter.xpath('.//td[8]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'losses': fighter.xpath('.//td[9]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'draws': fighter.xpath('.//td[10]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
            }
            
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(FightersSpider)
c.start()
```